# I want display array in following format

Tags: php, arrays

```
array1 = array(1 => a, 2 => a, 3 => a, 4 => b, 5 => b, 6 => c);
```

I want to display this array in following format that is:

> a
>      1
>      2
>      3
>     b
>      4
>      5
>     c
>      6

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? A simple `loop` and a new `array` could help.

Comment: What is the logic in your order? Because I can't see a logic, I can't suggest some code. Can you explain how came to this order?

Comment: Yes  I tried from my side but the result will be wrong.Some friends from stack overflow given me the solution.thanks ..

Answer (score 5):

This will do the job.

```
$array = array(1=>'a',2=>'a',3=>'a',4=>'b',5=>'b',6=>'c');

$occurances = array_count_values($array);
foreach ($occurances as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key".implode("",array_keys($array, $key)); 
}
```

*Note: This will print the result in-line. If you want to show the result as shown in your new edit, change the code as follows*

```
$occurances = array_count_values($array);
$str = "";// modification starts here 
foreach ($occurances as $key => $value) {
    $finds = $key."<br/>".implode("<br/>",array_keys($array, $key));
    $str .=  ($str=="")?$finds:"<br/>".$finds; 
}
echo $str;
```

**array_count_values()** Returns an associative array of values from array as keys and their count as value. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

**array_keys()** will return the key from the array.You can use an optional search_value to get only the keys for that values. Find more about array_keys() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: This is really an efficient 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array1 = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'a', 3 => 'a', 4 => 'b', 5 => 'b', 6 => 'c');

$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $key=>$val)
{
   $new_array[$val][] = $key;
}

$string = '';
foreach($new_array as $key=>$val)
{
  $string .= $key."\n".implode("\n",$val)."\n";
}

echo $string;
```